# Read a sequence of positive numbers and print their binary representation

Tags: c++, binary, sequence

Hey programmers can anyone help me with the task in the title,
example input : `3,8`
example output : `11,1000`
so far i found a way to turn the decimal numbers into binary with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int convertDecimalToBinary(int);

int main()
{
    int deci, binaryNumber;

    cout << "Enter a decimal number: ";
    cin >> deci;
    binaryNumber = convertDecimalToBinary(deci);
    cout << deci << " in decimal = " << binaryNumber << " in binary" << endl ;
    return 0;
}

int convertDecimalToBinary(int deci)
{
    int binaryNumber = 0;
    int remainder, i = 1;

    while (deci!=0)
    {
        remainder = deci%2;
        deci /= 2;
        binaryNumber += remainder*i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return binaryNumber;
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to read the sequence of numbers from the input. I looked around, but couldn't find a way to read the numbers, which are separated by commas, in the sequence.
Can anyone show me or tell me a way to do it.

Comment: A 32-bit `int` type can only hold 9 binary digits as a decimal number. Use strings instead.

Comment: As for your problem, how about starting with a loop? And there are probably thousands of examples on how to parse *Comma Separated Values* if you just search a little.

Comment: *But i can't seem to find a way to read the sequence of numbers from the input* -- So is the issue the reading in of numbers separated by commas?  If so, then that is what your question's title should reflect, and not be concerned with "printing binary".

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate.  Many examples can be found by searching the internet for "c++ decimal to binary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a loop to input each decimal number. IMHO, easiest way is to read the input sequence in a string and then read integer one by one. I will leave printing output as comma separated for you to figure out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int convertDecimalToBinary(int);

int main()
{
    int deci, binaryNumber;

    std::string decimal_sequence;
    cout << "Enter a decimal number: ";
    cin >> decimal_sequence;
    std::istringstream din(decimal_sequence);
    while(din >> deci) {
            binaryNumber = convertDecimalToBinary(deci);
            cout << deci << " in decimal = " << binaryNumber << " in binary" << endl ;
            char comma;
            din >> comma;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and thank you for not giving me the full answer on a silver plate so i can actually struggle a little for the solution :D But can you clarify how exactly istringstream works,i looked it up,but can't fully comprehend as i am still new to programming.

Comment: `istringstream` works like `cin` except that it reads from the string passed instead of command line. I am using it because, it is tricky to read from terminal in your case because the program does not know when to stop reading next integer. When using `istringstream`, it knows to stop when there are no more data.